# Call servlet from servlet, and JSP (wo Form) within one application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to call Servlet from another Servlet? both in one app.

```
public class DBaddData extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ....some actions here...
    ...get data from JSP...
    ...call INSERT INTO method...
    ...and then I want to call SELECT servlet...


    RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/myServlets/DBselTankList");
    view.forward(req, resp);
}

}
```

But I got only:

> The requested resource is not available.

"Select servlet" calls select method from DB and then show JSP with results

```
public class DBselTankList extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
 DBSelectRows dbSR = new DBSelectRows();  

    List<DBObjBaseStd> dboBStd=new ArrayList<DBObjBaseStd>();

    dboBStd=dbSR.sel(DBConnStrings.driver, DBConnStrings.url, DBConnStrings.dbName, DBConnStrings.userName, DBConnStrings.password, DBConnStrings.sslState);

    req.setAttribute("list", dboBStd);
    RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("selectedTankList.jsp");
    view.forward(req, resp);
}

}
```

I also want to get this **selectedTankList.jsp** by link from header

```
<a href="selectedTankList.jsp">Tank list</a>
```

But how to call "Select servlet" without **form** and **submit** button?

Comment: yeah, partly. My question is about `href` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I've found out.
When you call `Servlet` by clicking link (i.e. you call first Servlet that execute code inside `doGet` and only after that it send JSP to client) you need to put URL for `href` and this must be what you put between tags `<url-pattern>...</url-pattern>` in your `web.xml` during the mapping target servlet. 
For the example above it must be:

```
<a href="DBselTankList">Tank list</a>
```

Why `DBselTankList`? Because look at my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-name>DBselTankList</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>myServlets.DBselTankList</servlet-class>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DBselTankList</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DBselTankList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

BTW, the names are not good, shame on me. I have to take time to study the good approach in naming.
So, when you call `Servlet` from another `Servlet` (both in one project) do it like this:

```
RequestDispatcher view =  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DBselTankList");
view.forward(req, resp);
```

Namely, add "**/**" before the same name as for `href`